# How to use react-hook-form with form action

Tags: reactjs, forms, next.js, next.js13

This code doesn't trigger any validation on submit. This is the part where the login logic happens using Zod for validation and React Hook Form for handling the form. For some reason, the validation doesn't happen, and a call to the login action is fired without even checking the input contents. Can someone figure out why this happens?

Also is it even possible to use React Hook Form with actions?

```
const FormSchema = z.object({
  email: z
    .string()
    .min(1, { message: "This field has to be filled." })
    .email("This is not a valid email."),

  password: z
    .string()
    .min(4, { message: "Password must be at least 4 characters long." }),
});

const LogInForm = ({}: IProps) => {
  const { session, setSession } = useAuth();
  console.log("value", session);

  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();
  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof FormSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(FormSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    },
  });

  const handleLogin = async (formData: FormData) => {
    const email = formData.get("email") as string;
    const password = formData.get("password") as string;
    let user = await signIn(email, password);
    if (isUser(user)) {
      const { email, isSignedIn, error } = user;
      if (error.isError) {
        toast({
          title: `${error?.message}`,
          variant: "destructive",
          action: <XCircle size={25} />,
        });
      } else {
        setSession(user);
        toast({
          title: `${email} logged in successfully!`,
          variant: "success",
          action: <CheckCircle size={25} />,
        });

        redirect("/dashboard");
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form
        action={(formData) => startTransition(() => handleLogin(formData))}
        className="w-2/3 space-y-6"
      >
        <h1 className="text-4xl text-center font-semibold">Login</h1>
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="email"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
              <FormControl>
                <Input type="email" {...field} />
              </FormControl>
              <FormMessage />
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="password"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
              <FormControl>
                <Input type="password" {...field} />
              </FormControl>
              <FormMessage />
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />
        <Button
          type="submit"
          className="w-full"
        >
          Login
        </Button>
      </form>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default LogInForm;
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing action attribute on the `<Form>` element with `onSubmit`.

If that doesn't help please use `handleSubmit`  function returned by React Hook Form to handle form submission.

```
const { handleSubmit } = form;
 <Form {...form} onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleLogin)}>
  <form className="w-2/3 space-y-6">
```